# How do I check for a specific char within a string?

Tags: c++, string, indexing, chess

Disclaimer: I am super new to c++ and programming in general.

I have a function that takes in a string parameter that is only 2 integers long. I want to use the first and second int of the parameter to index into the chessBoard[8][8] to select a space on the board. Each index (space) in the 2D array (board) contains a char representing a piece type.

The function is supposed to determine the piece type, then call a move function for the specific piece.

Here is a part of the code applied to the king piece.

```
int movePiece(string startPos) {

string pieceType = chessBoard[startPos[0]][startPos[1]];

cout << chessBoard[startPos[0]][startPos[1]] <<endl;

if (tolower(pieceType) == 'k') {
    kingMove(startPos);
}
```

Line 5 is a test to see what exactly is being returned. For some reason it prints a " " (space) which means it is comparing " " to 'k' or any of the other chars representing piece types. Yet I can put 'cout >> chessBoard[0][3]' and have it print a 'k' (the piece on that space on the board). A space is also returned for any space on the board, not just [0][3].

'startPos' is a string, so I should be able to use startPos[0] and startPos[1] with a stringstream to access the integers, right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: std::tolower accepts `char` values. So you can use `tolower(pieceType[0])`. Why don't you simply use char[8][8] instead of std::string[8][8]?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error/current behaviour. Are you trying to index an array with characters? You have to convert them to integers. For example, `'0' != 0`, `'1' != 1`, etc.

Comment: Ah, so using string[8][8] wouldn't work with tolower? Thanks, I'll change it to char[8][8]. The current problem though is accessing the values stored in chessBoard.

Comment: Right now it always returns " " istead of whatever letter is in the array. I can easily do chessBoard[int][int] and it works, but I need to extract the integers from the user's input which is put into startPos. For this I tried startPos[0] for the first coord then startPos[1] for the next coord into the chessBoard. startPos could be "23" for example and therefore startPos[0] should be '2', right? For some reason it always returns " ". It is hard to tell if it is returning a space or just nothing at all, so it could be that too.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying. startPos[0] will return a char, not an int? So I need to convert startPos[0] and startPos[1] to integers before using them as coordinates to index chessBoard?

Comment: startPos[0] will return a char, but as the chess board is just 8x8 a char is as good as an int, that is not a problem, but mind you that '0' is not the same as 0. '0' is actually 48, '1' is 49 and so on, see https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table&atb=v80-7__&ia=answer&iax=answer